# Rust macro for repeating array elements

Tags: arrays, rust, macros, rust-macros

I'm trying to write a Rust macro that fills up an array with repeating elements, in this case with zeros. This is what I came up with:

```
macro_rules! pad4  {
    () => {
        println!("0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000");
    }
}

const arr: [u8; 8] = [pad4!(), 0b01111100, 0b10000010, 0b00000010, 0b01111110];
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
expected `u8`, found `()`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust macros aren't simple string replacements, they pattern match over parsed tokens and must return Rust syntax that is valid in the context the macro is invoked in.

Your current macro:

```rust
macro_rules! pad4  {
    () => {
        println!("0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000");
    }
}
```

Called in this context:

```rust
const arr: [u8; 8] = [pad4!(), 0b01111100, 0b10000010, 0b00000010, 0b01111110];
```

Expands to this:

```rust
const arr: [u8; 8] = [
    {
        println!("0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000");
    },
    0b01111100,
    0b10000010,
    0b00000010,
    0b01111110,
];
```

Which is why you're getting an error, as the first expression block in the array returns `()` instead of the expected `u8`.

You can use e.g. [`cargo expand`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-expand) to easily inspect the result of macro expansion.

---

Here's `pad4` but written in a way that works:

```rust
macro_rules! pad4 {
    [$($e:expr),*] => {
        [0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, $($e,)*]
    }
}

const arr: [u8; 8] = pad4![0b01111100, 0b10000010, 0b00000010, 0b01111110];
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=62ddba19e55c06774c4b37ffca4b0c73)

If you're brand new to Rust's declarative macros the go-to resource to learn them in-depth is [The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/README.html).

Comment: Thank you, yes, I'm quite new to Rust. So there is absolutely no way to insert code like with C macros?

Comment: I'm not a macros expert in either C or Rust, so I can't say for certain. Aside from the book I recommend in my answer you may also find this resource helpful: [Porting C Macros to Rust](https://locka99.gitbooks.io/a-guide-to-porting-c-to-rust/content/features_of_rust/macros.html).